# Botones dinámicos en tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Lo que estoy queriendo hacer es que cuando le des al botón "agregar" se agregue una serie de botones y entry´s. A medida que vaya cargando productos se puedan ir agregando mas de lo mismo hasta que lleno el frame y puede verse hacia abajo con un scrollbar

```py
import tkinter as tk
import os
os.system("cls")
raiz=tk.Tk()
frame_prod=tk.Frame(raiz)
frame_prod.pack()

def add():
    print("entro a add")
    global m
    global a

    m.append(a)
    x=len(m)-1
    p=len(m) + 1
    for f in range(x,x+1):|
        for c in range(len(m[0])):
            print("M[",f,"][",c,"]=","ubica el objeto en la fila:",p,"columna:",c)
            if c == 0 or c == 1:
                m[f][c].grid(row=p,column=c,padx=8,ipadx=10)
            else:
                m[f][c].grid(row=p,column=c)
    #------------------------------
    print("tamaño de M:",len(m))
    for f in range(len(m)):
        for c in range(len(m[0])):
            print(m[f][c])
        print("\n")
    #------------------------------
def productos(frame_prod):
    global m
    global a
    tk.Label(frame_prod,text="---Productos---",height=1,justify="center").grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=10,pady=10)
    tk.Label(frame_prod,text="Codigo").grid(row=1,column=2,columnspan=2)
    tk.Label(frame_prod,text="Descrpcion").grid(row=1,column=4,columnspan=2)
    tk.Label(frame_prod,text="Cant").grid(row=1,column=6)
    tk.Label(frame_prod,text="Bon%").grid(row=1,column=7)
    tk.Label(frame_prod,text="Precio/U").grid(row=1,column=8)
    tk.Label(frame_prod,text="Importe").grid(row=1,column=9)

    for f in range(len(m)):
        for c in range(len(m[0])):
            if c == 0 or c == 1:
                m[f][c].grid(row=f+2,column=c,padx=8,ipadx=10)
            else:
                m[f][c].grid(row=f+2,column=c)

a = [tk.Button(frame_prod,text="-"),tk.Button(frame_prod,text="+",command=add),tk.Entry(frame_prod,width=10),tk.Button(frame_prod,text="-"),tk.Entry(frame_prod,width=10),tk.Button(frame_prod,text="-"),tk.Entry(frame_prod,width=10),tk.Entry(frame_prod,width=10),tk.Entry(frame_prod,width=10),tk.Entry(frame_prod,width=10)]
m = [a,]
productos(frame_prod)
raiz.mainloop()
```

Necesito hacerlo sin usar clases, creo que sería lo mejor, y el código tiene esa estructura porque pertenece a un fragmento de otro código mas grande

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu lista `a` contiene objetos ya instanciados de *tkinter*, no clases. No funciona porque estás ejecutando `grid` secuencialmente sobre los mismos objetos, no sobre copias de los mismos, que es lo que creo que pretendes hacer.

Tu lista `m` crece dentro de la función `add`, pero solo contiene referencias a los mismos objetos iniciales, no a nuevos objetos.

He modificado tu código utilizando la función predefinida `eval` para volver a ejecutar las intrucciones de tu lista `a` dentro de la función `add` (en este ejemplo `a` no es una lista, sino un *string* que representa a una lista), de modo que los nuevos objetos creados si pueden ser mostrados con `grid`:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
os.system("cls")
raiz=tk.Tk()
frame_prod=tk.Frame(raiz)
frame_prod.pack()

def add():
    print("entro a add")
    global m
    global a

    m.append(eval(a))
    x=len(m)-1
    p=len(m) + 1
    for f in range(x,x+1):
        for c in range(len(m[0])):
            print("M[",f,"][",c,"]=","ubica el objeto en la fila:",p,"columna:",c)
            if c == 0 or c == 1:
                m[f][c].grid(row=p,column=c,padx=8,ipadx=10)
            else:
                m[f][c].grid(row=p,column=c)
    #------------------------------
    print("tamaño de M:",len(m))
    for f in range(len(m)):
        for c in range(len(m[0])):
            print(m[f][c])
        print("\n")
    #------------------------------
def productos(frame_prod):
    global m
    global a
    tk.Label(frame_prod,text="---Productos---",height=1,justify="center").grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=10,pady=10)
    tk.Label(frame_prod,text="Codigo").grid(row=1,column=2,columnspan=2)
    tk.Label(frame_prod,text="Descrpcion").grid(row=1,column=4,columnspan=2)
    tk.Label(frame_prod,text="Cant").grid(row=1,column=6)
    tk.Label(frame_prod,text="Bon%").grid(row=1,column=7)
    tk.Label(frame_prod,text="Precio/U").grid(row=1,column=8)
    tk.Label(frame_prod,text="Importe").grid(row=1,column=9)

    for f in range(len(m)):
        for c in range(len(m[0])):
            if c == 0 or c == 1:
                m[f][c].grid(row=f+2,column=c,padx=8,ipadx=10)
            else:
                m[f][c].grid(row=f+2,column=c)

a = """
[
    tk.Button(frame_prod,text="-"),
    tk.Button(frame_prod,text="+",command=add),
    tk.Entry(frame_prod,width=10),tk.Button(frame_prod,text="-"),
    tk.Entry(frame_prod,width=10),tk.Button(frame_prod,text="-"),
    tk.Entry(frame_prod,width=10),tk.Entry(frame_prod,width=10),
    tk.Entry(frame_prod,width=10),tk.Entry(frame_prod,width=10)
]
"""

m = [eval(a)]

productos(frame_prod)
raiz.mainloop()
```

La función predefinida `eval` te permite *evaluar* una cadena de texto para que sea interpretada como código. Cada vez que se ejecuta `eval(a)` (siendo `a` una cadena) se crea una **nueva lista con nuevos objetos que nada tienen que ver con los objetos creados anteriormente**.

Ahora la lista `m` si es una lista de listas que contiene **nuevos *widgets*** cada vez que se ejecuta la función `add`.

**Otra solución** sería que `a` sea una función que devuelve una lista:

```
def a():
    return [tk.Button(frame_prod,text="-"),tk.Button(frame_prod,text="+",command=add),tk.Entry(frame_prod,width=10),tk.Button(frame_prod,text="-"),tk.Entry(frame_prod,width=10),tk.Button(frame_prod,text="-"),tk.Entry(frame_prod,width=10),tk.Entry(frame_prod,width=10),tk.Entry(frame_prod,width=10),tk.Entry(frame_prod,width=10)]

# O mediante una función lambda:
# a = lambda:[tk.Button(frame_prod,text="-"),tk.Button(frame_prod,text="+",command=add),tk.Entry(frame_prod,width=10),tk.Button(frame_prod,text="-"),tk.Entry(frame_prod,width=10),tk.Button(frame_prod,text="-"),tk.Entry(frame_prod,width=10),tk.Entry(frame_prod,width=10),tk.Entry(frame_prod,width=10),tk.Entry(frame_prod,width=10)]
```

La función `a()` devuelve una **nueva lista con nuevos objetos** cada vez que se ejecuta.

En este caso debes sustituir `a` por `a()` para referirte a la lista que devuelve la función y no a la función en sí: `m = [a()]`

También, en este caso, tendrías que sustituir `a` por `a()` dentro de la función `add`.

Personalmente me decantaría por esta segunda solución. Siempre que sea posible evita utilizar `eval`.

**NOTA:** No es necesario que utilices `global m` ni `global a` en tus funciones, ya que no estás utilizando el operador de asignación (`=`) sobre estas variables. Es decir, `m` y `a` siempre apuntan al mismo objeto aunque lo modifiques con su método `append`.

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias amigo! me enseñaste mas de lo que crees, aprendí mucho luego de esto...un abrazo

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! me alegro de haber sido útil :D. Un saludo amigo!